# Are all triangles isosceles

Tags: geometry

[image]

I was reading a geometry book [(HSM Coexeter's Geometry revisited)](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM0YeHq83WAhUFQo8KHeI4ArwQFggsMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aproged.pt%2Fbiblioteca%2Fgeometryrevisited_coxetergreitzer.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1WfgNAAsz-rSOmj2_G4edH) and I found something interesting about tritangent circles.

Let $r_a$ be the radius of excircle from $I_a$

then $ar(ABC)=rs=r_a(s-a)$....
$r=\text{inradius}$ and $s=\text{semiperimeter}$ and $a=BC$, $b=AC$, $c=AB$

Now,  As $\triangle AIY_b$ is similar to $\triangle AI_aY_a$
therefore 
$$\frac{AY_b}{AY_a}=\frac{s-c}{s}=\frac{r}{r_a}$$
which means $$rs=r_a(s-c)$$
Combining this with above equation gives 
$$a=c?$$

What's the flaw in the above reasoning?

NOTE:
$AZ_a=AY_a$ as these are tangents...

$AZ_a+AY_a=AB+CA+BX_a+CX_a=AB+BC+CA=2s$

$\therefore AZ_a=AY_a=s$

NOTE:
$AII_a,AY_bY_a$ are straight lines..join $I_aY_a$

Now $\angle AY_bI=\angle AY_aI_a=90$
and $\angle IAY_b=\angle I_aAY_a$
therefore triangles are similar.

Comment: what an exircle?

Comment: "then 4ar(ABC)=rs=r_a(s−a)$"  I'll assume ar(ABC) means area of the triangle ABC, but what is r, s, and a and why would this statement be true?

Comment: Not all triangles can create such tritangent circles.  Why should we be surprised that only equilateral triangles can?  In fact my intuition says any triangle that isn't equilateral would make the image imposible.  Circle a being tangent means AI_a is perpendicular to BC and ... thus isoceles.

Comment: @fleablood Circle $AI_a$ is tangent at $X_a$

Comment: No it's not: you can see that the tangent point  is not on the line $A I_a$. You can't see it for the other two lines because of the way you've drawn the triangle. If you draw a triangle whose sides are very different from each other, you will see that the line between a vertex and the corresponding excircle center does not meet the point of tangency. In general, the points $A, X_a, I_a$ and similarly for B and C do *not* lie on a straight line.

Comment: Why do you think that $AI_a$ is tangent to the incircle at all? The incircle is tangent to the side.  And the excircle is tangent to the side.  But they are not nescessarily tangent at the *same* point.  Your post PROVES that if the *are* tangent at the same point then the triangle must be isoceles.  And, contrapositively, if the triangle *isn't* isoceles the circles will not be tangent at the same point.

Comment: Why does $Y_bY_a = AB$?

Comment: Its proved in the book just below the page I told you..

Comment: I have gotten very confused now due to this question..

Comment: Maybe this will help: assuming $Y_b$ is the point of tangency between the excircle with center $I_b$ and line $A C$, the line between $I$ and $I_b$ in general does *NOT* pass through $Y_b$. The only time that it *does* pass through $Y_b$ is when the triangle is isosceles: $BA = BC$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, you seem to be inferring incidences from an unclear diagram. Here's an improved version:

[image]

Here, I hope you'll see that the points of tangency (which I've denoted $X$, $Y$, $Z$) of the incircle do not generally coincide with those ($X_a$, $Y_b$, $Z_c$) of the excircles. Moreover, neither of those points usually lies on the angle bisectors ($\overline{AI_a}$, $\overline{BI_b}$, $\overline{CI_c}$).

It is true, however, that when (and only when) two sides of the triangle are congruent, the points of tangency on the third side *do* coincide, and they lie on the corresponding angle bisector. So, your conclusion was "correct" based on your interpretation of the diagram; unfortunately (but somewhat understandably), your interpretation of the diagram was *incorrect*.

Comment: I had also noticed the same today..

Comment: Nice diagram! Thanks for providing it.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I can tell there is no flaw.  That diagram only exists for equilateral triangles.

From Wolfram "Note that the three excircles are not necessarily tangent to the incircle, and so these four circles are not equivalent to the configuration of the Soddy circles".

In this diagram the three excircles *are* tangent to the incircle.  That can only occur if the triangle is equilateral.

For point $X_a$ to exist the incircle must be tangent to the excircle.  That can only happen if $AI_a$ is perpendicular to $BC$ and that can only happen if the triangle is isoceles.  This diagram of the excircles (tangent to all three extended lines of the triangle) being **ALSO** tangent to the incircle, can only occurs with equilateral triangles.

Comment: Can you please provide a proof? Your comment isn't quite clear...Even in Wikipedia it is mentioned "Every triangle has three distinct excircles, each tangent to one of the triangle's sides"

Comment: For point $X_a$ to exist the in circle must be tangent to the excircle.  That can only happen if $AI_a$ is perpendicular to $BC$ that can only happen if the triangle is isoceles.  This diagram of the excircles (tangent to all three extended lines of the triangle) being ALSO tangent to the incircle, can only occure with equilateral triangles.

Comment: Who said that $X_a$ is the common tangent point of both circles...

Comment: You did, not for $X_a$ but for $Y_b$. Otherwise the similarity you use is not true.

Comment: What *IS* $X_a$ then?

Comment: The tangency point of only the excircle....

Comment: Why do you say that $AIY_b$ is similar to $AI_bY_a$?  Angle $AIY_b$ is not equal to $AI_bY_a$ (unless $X_a$ is the point of tangency of both circles.)

Comment: Why is that? There are two right angles and a common angle $I_aAY_a$

Comment: Right angles?  There aren't any right angles.

Comment: $AY_bI$ and $AY_aI_a$ are both right

Comment: Please answer my question

Comment: "There are two right angles and a common angle $I_aAY_a$"  $AIY_b$ contains angle $IAY_a$ and $AI_aY_a$ contains angle $I_aAY_a$.  Angle  $IAY_a$ and angle $I_aAY_a$ are not the same angle unless $I_a, I, A$ are colinear.  ANd they are only colinear if the incircle and excircle are tangent to each other.

Comment: @fleablood.....It is proved in the book they are collinear...Pg 12 of book and Pg 18 of pdf file

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Why do you think that $II_a = AB$? or that $s= AI_a$?

Comment: I dont know it just happened...but is my reasoning correct..By the way it is a ratio..not direct lengths

Comment: Why do you thing $AY_b = s - c$.  That seems to mean you assume $Y_aY_b = c$.  Why?

Comment: @fleablood...its also proved in the book

Answer (score 1):

[Made an answer out of part of my comment.]

If you draw a triangle whose sides are very different from each other, you will see that the line between a vertex and the corresponding excircle center does not meet the point of tangency. In general, the points $A,X_a,I_a$ and similarly for $B$ and $C$ do not lie on a straight line.

Comment: But what difference does that make?

Comment: It proves that there is at least one triangle that is not isosceles, so the answer to your question is "no". It also shows that when you draw a diagram, you can fool yourself badly, by choosing to draw a special case that you then generalize to something that is wrong.

Comment: But where in my reasoning have I used $A,X_a,I_a$ are collinear..I have only compared areas which result in the above contradiction

Comment: How did you construct point I?

Comment: Its the incentre.. You can check this if you have a copy of the book I mentioned

Comment: How do you construct point $X_a$?

Comment: ... and perhaps more pertinently, point $Y_b$?

Comment: What *ARE* the points supposed to represent?  Point of tangency to the incircle? Excircle?  Both? Neither?  "But where in my reasoning have I used A,Xa,Ia are collinear."  when you claimed AIY_b is similar to AI_aY_a.

Comment: I just used the theorem that external bisectors of two angles is concurrent with the internal bisector of the third

Comment: What external bisectors?  What internal bisectors?  Look.  Just *draw* a triangle where the incircles and excircles are not tangent.  You'll see those triangles are very much not similar.

Comment: I have provided a link of that book....Can you check Pg12..There is the diagram

Comment: $I_bB$ does not bisect angle $I_b$.

Comment: Yes it doesnt...What difference does that make?

Comment: Read th 1.51 in your cited book.  In that Diagram if the points in and ex circles are not cotangent (which they appear to be) then I can not see why the triangles you claim to be similar are similar and you book never claims they are.

Comment: Can you also see the answers at Pg156 Q5 of the book...168 in pdf